# How to set default homepage for subdomain on iis7?

Tags: iis-7, subdomain, default

I've already set default homepage for "www.mydomain.com" sucessfully.
Now, I want to set default homepage for "sub.mydomain.com", but it throw 404 page if i don't type "sub.mydomain.com/default.aspx" ?
The first and the second site are separate physical folders and virtual directories on iis7.

Comment: Specify con server configuration please! Same server with just one IP on por 80? The "sub" name pointer is just an alias or is pointing to another IP? DNS configuration

Comment: Both of them on the same server with just one ip, port 80.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly, you have a single web server with many sites all on port 80 and you are using host headers to control which site a request goes to.

In this case you must specify the whole address, otherwise the server does not know which site to send it to.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, default site, properties, web site, advanced, you should see a list like;

```
default - 80
```

then "Add" in these two rows

```
 (all unassigned) : 80 : www.mydomain.com
 (all unassigned) : 80 : sub.mydomain.com
```

then default.aspx will go to the same page in both sites. ie. sub.mydomain.com is the same as www.mydomain.com.

However, if you want sub.mydomain.com to be a different website, then remove it from that list above and from IIS, Websites -> New Website ... yadda yadda yadda, then add in sub.mydomain.com as you did above.